# How to run command within an interactive shell via python (boto for AWS)

Tags: python, shell, amazon-web-services, ssh

I am trying to run some commands to an AWS EC2 instance remotely via ssh within the python boto ssh module (which uses paramiko package).  I am using boto.manage.cmdshell.sshclient_from_instance.run which works fine but the problem is that with .run is that it cannot do sudo command remotely.  I get this error message:

```
sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

I know I can manually login and edit permission to fix that but I want that part to be automated as well.  I can launch an interactive shell using .shell but is there a way to automate commands within that interactive shell using python?

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`boto.manage.cmdshell.SSHClient.run_pty(command)`](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/stable/ref/manage.html#boto.manage.cmdshell.SSHClient.run_pty) instead. It will request a pseudo-terminal and execute the command.

See the post [How does paramiko Channel.recv() exactly work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24125182/how-does-paramiko-channel-recv-exactly-work) to see how you can read standard output.

Comment: Yea I should've mentioned that but what I noticed with that command is that I cannot simply do a print to see the output (while it does give output they are not the same as print).  Also I noticed someone asked that question before but there was no answer. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27711530/correct-way-to-get-output-of-run-pty-from-a-boto-sshclient)

I supposed what I can do is to use .run_pty to quickly change the permission so I can use .run.

Comment: True but I have maybe about a week of actual python coding experience so would have prefer an easier way out. :o

Comment: You should take a look to [paramiko.channel.Channel.exec_command documentation](http://docs.paramiko.org/en/1.16/api/channel.html#paramiko.channel.Channel.exec_command).

Comment: This post might also help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24125182/how-does-paramiko-channel-recv-exactly-work

Answer (score 1):

I ended up fixing it by using .run_pty and then edit the sudoers file to not requiretty.  Afterward I just use sudo with .run